# How to find the equal and opposite rows in a table

Tags: sql

How to find the equal and opposite rows in a table.

E.g.:

```
book position
A    500
B    500
C    500
```

The output should return the rows having equal and opposite positions.

O/P:

```
A 500
B 500
```

I have tried self join on a table but in vain.Do we need to cursors for these row level handling?

Comment: If you post the schema and the queries you have tried it is much easier to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the requirements, but I guess you want something like:

```
select T1.X, T1.Y, T2.X, T2.Y
from T as T1
join T as T2
    on abs(T1.Y) = abs(T2.Y)
```

You might also want to add a predicate like:

```
    and T1.X < T2.X
```

if you don't want the symmetric solutions